# Combining indicator variables

Tags: stata

I am using the [CCES](https://cces.gov.harvard.edu/) 2016 dataset.

I am only interested in whites who have a high school diploma or less (that is, no college), and who identify as democrats.

The three variables are `race`, `educ`, and `pid3`:

- `race = 1` if white
- `educ = 2` if high school diploma and `educ = 1` if not
- `pid3 = 1` if democrat

I would like to create a new variable made up of people who selected `1` for `race`; `1` or `2` for `educ`; and `1` for `pid3`.

What commands should I type in Stata 13 to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm going to assume that you mean to create a variable that is equal to 1 if it matches your conditions and missing if not. Hint: look at ```generate``` and the ```if``` qualifier

Comment: I should guess that very few Stata experts know what the CCES 2016 dataset is. For that and other reasons, please study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the standard here.

Comment: @YDavis Indicators that are 1 or missing are of little use in Stata for statistical or graphical purposes as observations with missing values will typically be omitted from any results. Indicators that are 1 or 0 are much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

For a (0, 1) indicator, consider

```
generate wanted = (race == 1) & inlist(educ, 1, 2) & (pid3 == 1)
```

See

1. the help for `operators` and `inlist()`
2. https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/

Comment: One can also use `inrange()` instead of `inlist()`.

Comment: @Pearly Spencer  In practice I am confident that would work too with what can be plausibly be guessed about the data. But in principle,`inrange(x, 1, 2)` and `inlist(x, 1, 2)` are not guaranteed identical in result as e.g. 1.5 matches the first but not the second.

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the case with indicators as in this example. My solutions/comments to questions are always case specific (unless i explicitly say otherwise) but most people appear to assume that these are also valid beyond their stated use case.

Comment: Fair enough. Equally, a question without some generality of application is a disappointing question.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that seemed to work. I realise I had been using a single = instead of two =.

Comment: Good, but if you had shown any code that would have been explained.